# Ошибка локализации сообщения о дубликате

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Опять сбилось сообщение о дубликате?

Ошибка локализации сообщения о дубликате.

При закрытии как дубликат в поясняющем сообщении выводится английский текст.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]